# Reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Tags: .net, sql-server, smo

I need to use [Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) class which is stored in Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll I don't see this assembly in usual References dialog. I have found it at C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/SDK/Assemblies and try to reference from there but Visual Studio throws an error "A reference 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/SDK/Assemblies/Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since 2017 nuget package is the right approach: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` is the correct folder location (or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` on 64-bit systems).

You need to add references to:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

(These are the minimum files that are required to build an SMO application)

For SQL Server 2016, this location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies` (for the 64bit version).

Ref.: [How to: Create a Visual C# SMO Project in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

The SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) are downloadable as part of the relevant [SQL Server (20XX) Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) (check the smallprint as I don't believe these are redistributable?)

Comment: On a 64-bit system those files are located in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

Answer (score 4):

For those who need the sql server 2014 version (version 120) you need to download and install the following packages from Microsoft:

- SQLSysClrTypes (x64): https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/3/0/13089488-91FC-4E22-AD68-5BE58BD5C014/ENU/x64/SQLSysClrTypes.msi
- SharedManagementObjects(x64): https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/3/0/13089488-91FC-4E22-AD68-5BE58BD5C014/ENU/x64/SharedManagementObjects.msi

You can find all relevant info on Microsoft website on this page (as suggested correctly by @mitch-wheat ):
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42295

Answer (score 2):

You can try this unofficial nuget package...

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO/

> Install-Package Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just ran into the same issue.   @Mitch_Wheat is correct that as a minimum you need references to the 4 SMO assemblies.  Trying to add all 4 at once, however, gave me the error you listed.

Adding the assemblies one at a time bypassed the error.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) NuGet package seams like the official way to install it after [SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install following package to solve the problem , I have solved this problem twice with this package hope it may work for everyone too...

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Management Objects Collection
The Management Objects Collection package includes several key elements of the SQL Server 2005 management API, including Analysis Management Objects (AMO), Replication Management Objects (RMO), and SQL Server Management Objects (SMO). Developers and DBAs can use these components to programmatically manage SQL Server 2005.

You can get from Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - December 2008 from Microsoft site [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11988][1] 
But the link location of download page changes every-time if you don't find resource you can download it from my blog too.

I have also provided some tips and resources about this in my blog if you want 
http://rndp-android.blogspot.com/p/missing-microsoftsqlservermanagementsdk.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you want use `Backup` class add Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoExtended to your project.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get all `7 ddls` that related on this issue is

> Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoExtended.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll,
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

Create a separate `console application`

download those using `nuget`

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO -Version 12.0.2000.8

build the application and all `dlls` will be in the `bin` folder ... you can copy from there and add `reference to your existing application`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO/12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects
see installation info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo

but no idea if this is redistributable...

as it only talks about design, develop and testing:

> 1. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.   You may install and use any number of copies of the software on your devices to design, develop and test
>      your programs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/smo-license-terms

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize a pull subscription on demand in Management Studio
Connect to the Subscriber in Management Studio, and then expand the server node.

Expand the Replication folder, and then expand the Local Subscriptions folder.

Right-click the subscription you want to synchronize, and then click View Synchronization Status.

In the View Synchronization Status - : dialog box, click Start. When synchronization is complete, the message Synchronization completed is displayed.

Click Close.

Answer (score -4):

Hmm.
Try registering the DLL library by running this at the DOS prompt (I'm curious as to why it's not registered already. I tried using it on a Windows that had SQL2008 installed and didn't have your problem)

> "c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL
>   Server/100/SDK/Assemblies/Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"

You need the quotation marks because of the spaces in the directory names.

If you're running a 64-bit Windows, regsvr32.exe will be in C:\windows\syswow64\

Best of luck. Let us know if this won't help..
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the usual signs that this is a COM object container (DllRegisterServer export, OleSelfRegister VS_VERSION_INFO entry). Does it really need to be regsvr32ed? Wouldn't that have made it a COM reference not an assembly reference?