# Looking for a tool for creating an export script for a whole SQL Sever database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a MS SQL Server 2008 database. 
I have all the rights to create and change tables, views, procedures, etc. 
**But I have no right to export or import the database.**

Therefore, I am looking for a tool which can **create a script with all the necessary CREATE / INSERT Statements** for all objects and all data lines in an MS SQL Server database.

The SQL Server Management Studio can do this partially, but only for single objects, not for whole all objects at once, and also not for data.

Is there any tool which can do this?

Comment: how about backup and restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your database in Enterprise Manager, Tasks, Generate Scripts. Follow the wizard. Don't forget to select "Script Data" in the options. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140422/generating-sql-script-through-code-c-net/12140494#12140494) for a PowerShell script doing what you want.

Comment: DAVID, THANK YOU SO MUCH! It works!!! I had always looked into the "Script Database" menu (which does not work), and so I have totally overseen that there is a second option in the "Tasks" menu. Great !