# How to export data from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please can someone tell me how I can easily export data from a SQL Server 2012 database? I have been trying for a while now and have read several articles but I either do not understand them or they are not what I am looking for.

I want to export ONLY the data itself to a single `.sql` file, is this possible and if so can somebody please tell me how I can do this?

I expect the code to be generated as `insert` statements eg.

```
insert into employee(id, name, address) 
values('1', 'Yao Ming', 'No.2 NBA Street');
```

Comment: right click on your database and select generate scripts.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat If that is the case, then wouldn't it have been much better if you had at least posted a link to one of those "many" links.  If you can't be helpful then don't post at all. Thank you.

Comment: Per definition that would not be a data export but the generation of a sql script - unless you plan to do something like storing a csv file in a .SQL file extension.

Comment: Done. VOting to close as duplicate. Reference in the closing link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140422/generating-sql-script-through-code-c-net/12140494#12140494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'Task' > 'Generate Script' > 'Set Scripting Option' > Advanced > 
'Types of data to script' > Select 'Data Only'.
Then generate the script.

Can refer to this link also: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/generating-script-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Sure mate :) . If it works for you you can accept as answer also :)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to phpmyadmin > Database > yourdatabasename > Export > go > copy and past code in any text editor > save in yourdatabasename.sql