# Is there a C# API for sys.tables and sys.procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Before I run off and write my own version from scratch, is there an API that exposes the system views in SQL Server (e.g. sys.tables and sys.procedures) to C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you suggest, you can use `ADO.NET` to query the [system catalogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx).

You could also use LINQ to SQL:

- Open Server Explorer in Visual Studio. Open a connection to the server.
- Right-click the server and choose Change View > Object Type.
- Under System Tables and User Tables,  you can drag a system object onto a .dbml surface.

---

For database specific objects use SMO (SQL Server Management Objects)

In C# add  [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx)

[SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

- [StoredProcedureCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.storedprocedurecollection.aspx)
- [ViewCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.viewcollection.aspx)
- [TableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.tablecollection.aspx)

This might be of use: [Reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453415/reference-microsoft-sqlserver-smo-dll)

Comment: SMO objects are awesome. They even have a decent caching system so I don't waste cycles fetching the same information twice.