# Getting always FALSE as a result of Table Exists method using C# SQLClient MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I have the code like this for checking if database exists:

```
    private bool CheckDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        var connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security = SSPI; database = master";           
        string cmdText = "select count(*) from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name=\'" + databaseName + "\'";         
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
            {                    
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(@"database", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = databaseName;                    
                sqlConnection.Open();                    
                return Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
            }
        }            
    }
```

EDIT:
I used the query from the comments but I am always getting false as a result:

```
public static bool CheckTableExists()
    {
        var connString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security = SSPI; database = master";
        string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = \'" + "databaseName" + "\' AND TABLE_NAME = \'" + "testingTable" + "\'";
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(@"database", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "databaseName";

                sqlConnection.Open();

                return Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot find the solution myself unless I will be able to put my hands on some slq learning resource.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464474/check-if-a-sql-table-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a C# API for sys.tables and sys.procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102044/is-there-a-c-sharp-api-for-sys-tables-and-sys-procedures)

Comment: the link you posted doesn't explain how to specify the database in which table exists(or not)

Comment: I will give it a read.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for tables existing in SQL pretty easily

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' 
AND  TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
```

Comment: excellent! Exactly what I was looking for. Can you direct me to the right place so I can learn building queries myself?

Comment: yes, I have no idea how to digest the thing. I'm totally new to it.

Comment: ah ok, w3schools is a great resource :D

Comment: @GiantJelly I tried this query on my code but I get always false as a result and the code attempts to create a table of such name, giving me error that table exists.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of databases (rather than tables):
    select name from sys.databases

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a `try .. catch` like below, make a query against the table and catch the `SqlException` like

```
    string cmdText = "select 1 from mytbl1";         
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
        {                    
            try
            {  
             sqlConnection.Open();                    
             return Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 1;
            }
            catch(SqlException ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```